# Save the current page of a pdf in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, pdfkit

I am trying to add the current page of a pdf into a dictionary, and go to the specific page once the user goes back to the PDF view.

`

```
import SwiftUI
import PDFKit
import SlidingTabView

struct PDFKitRepresentedView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL
    @Binding var pageNum: [String: Int]

    init(_ url: URL, _ pageNum: Binding<[String: Int]>) {
        self.url = url
        self._pageNum = pageNum
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) -> PDFKitRepresentedView.UIViewType {
        // Create a `PDFView` and set its `PDFDocument`.
        guard PDFDocument(url: self.url) != nil else { return UIView() }
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: self.url)
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        UserDefaults.standard.set(3, forKey: url.lastPathComponent)
//        pageNum[url.lastPathComponent] = 0
        
        return pdfView
    }
    
    

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) {
        // Update the view.
        guard let pdfView = uiView as? PDFView else { return }
        let savedPageNumber = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: url.lastPathComponent)
        print(savedPageNumber)
        pdfView.go(to: (pdfView.document?.page(at:savedPageNumber))!)
//        let pageNumber = pdfView.document?.index(for: pdfView.currentPage!) ?? 0
//        UserDefaults.standard.set(pageNumber, forKey: url.lastPathComponent)
//        pdfView.go(to: (pdfView.document?.page(at: pageNum[url.lastPathComponent]!))!)
    }
}

struct PDFKitView: View {
    var url: URL
    @Binding var pageNum: [String: Int]

    var body: some View {
        PDFKitRepresentedView(url, $pageNum)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showPicker = false
    @State private var fileURLs: [URL] = []
    @State private var tabs: [String] = []
    @State private var selectedTabIndex = 0
    @State private var pageNums: [String: Int] = [:]
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var barItems: some View {
        if !fileURLs.isEmpty && self.selectedTabIndex < fileURLs.count {
            PDFKitView(url: fileURLs[selectedTabIndex], pageNum: $pageNums)
                .id(selectedTabIndex)
        } else {
            Text("No File Selected")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                if !tabs.isEmpty {
                    SlidingTabView(selection: self.$selectedTabIndex, tabs: tabs)
                }
                barItems.padding()
                Spacer()
            }
//            .padding(.top, 50)
            .animation(.none, value: 0)
            .fileImporter(isPresented: $showPicker, allowedContentTypes: [.item]) { result in
                switch result {
                    case .success(let Fileurl):
                    var fileName = Fileurl.lastPathComponent
                        if self.tabs.isEmpty {
                            self.tabs.append(fileName)
                            self.tabs.append("Open a new file")
                        } else {
                            let index = self.tabs.lastIndex(of: "Open a new file")
                            var count = 0
                            for temp in tabs {
                                if temp == fileName {
                                    count += 1
                                }
                            }
                            if count != 0 {
                                fileName += " - " + String(count)
                            }
                            self.tabs[index!] = fileName
                            self.tabs.append("Open a new file")
                        }
                        self.fileURLs.append(Fileurl)
//                        self.pageNums.append(0)
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Tinjin", displayMode: .inline)
            .toolbar {
                Button {
                    print("Folder tapped!")
                    showPicker.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "folder")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

`

I have tried using the hash value and saving the current page, but cannot figure out how to accurately save the current page without generating a infinite loop within the updateUIView func

Answer (score 0):

When you debug your `updateUIView` function, like put a debug flag on the line with `pdfView.go(to:` you see that your PDFView is not shown on a device right now. I solved this by executing the `go(to:` code 2 seconds later (this is not a good practice, only for debugging):

```
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
        for _ in 0..<savedPageNumber {
            if pdfView.canGoToNextPage {
                pdfView.goToNextPage(nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see now this code works. Probably with this knowledge you can solve the asyncAfter puzzle, or someone else can help who has more experience with `UIViewRepresentable`.

Also I'd suggest minor improvements. For example in line

```
let pageNumber = pdfView.document?.index(for: pdfView.currentPage!) ?? 0
```

When the PDF Document is initialized it doesn't mean that it has any page, or does it? So even page at index 0 is not sure if it's there. Make it a `!` to be sure you get the page you want or a crash.